# Network based monitor output to smart TV

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, display, tv

TL;DR

I want my TV to act as a PC monitor but due to the distance between my TV and computer, a normal (VGA/HDMI etc) isn't an option. How do I achieve this?

---

I've got a server, that has windows 8.1 (using software that is not capable of running on a real server OS).
I've got a Philips 49PUS7909 TV.

The server stands in a room apart, with nothing else then an ethernet cable and power.

Now I want to see the monitor output of this machine on my TV.

Because of the distance a regular HDMI cable is not an option.
I know that my TV is miracast compliant, but for this I should have a wireless card with WIFI direct.
That is not the case here, and I even don't know for sure if the wireless signals should reach each other.

Both the windows machine and the TV are connected through a gigabit cable (and this is working: using it for media streaming).

Does someone know of a way I haven't thought of to accomplish this?
Something that I can think of (but haven't found anything to do this... yet) is faking a wireless card, and be able to fake miracast onto my cabled network...

Comment: Sorry to ask this, I didn't fully understnd the situation, but, are you wanting to 'stream' from the server to your TV?

Comment: @Dave I want to 'stream' the output that you normally would have on a monitor over my network to my TV.

Comment: In that case, use Powerline Adapters. This is what I do. My TV is too far away from the NAS or PC. And the wireless is not strong enough. I simply buy 3 power line adapters, use 1 for my Router, 1 for my source (NAS) and 1 for the destination (TV). Then I use my SmartTV to browse my NAS and play Spongebob, on repeat... constantly... or else my children get more annoying!

Comment: @Dave No, that is not the case. I have a working network setup, wherein my computer and TV are connected (and can see each other, I can already stream files over DLNA right now). What I want is that the output that you normally should see on your monitor (connected through VGA, DVI, HDMI or something else) 'stream' to my TV, just like my TV is the monitor. But it needs to be over ethernet instead of a regular HDMI (or ...) cable.

Comment: @Blaatpraat Hey unless there is a specific application you can get for your TV this is not possible. An ethernet port natively does not transfer Display Signal therefore you would need an application that would speak to Windows via a networking protocol and transfer Windows Display. Much like you can use remote desktop connection from one PC to another, or another example would be VNC.

Comment: @CharlesH That's why I specifically mentioned my TV model, maybe there was someone that knew something like that. On the other hand, I forgot to mention that this TV is running Android, and can install almost every Android app. So let's search for a VNC app in android this evening.

Comment: @Blaatpraat Hey, yeah I would have done some digging but don't like to recommend any apps that I haven't personally tested. With Android you should be able to get a RDP client or a VNC client, both of these will need you to setup the client side so for RDP you need to enable remote desktop (can explain more if you struggle), for VNC you will need to get a VNC Server application as it is not native to Windows.

Comment: I'm trying to help, don't be annoyed at my question, but are you just saying you want your TV to act as your PC monitor but due to the distance a normal (VGA/HDMI etc) doesn't work

Comment: @Dave Indeed, that's the question indeed. The only connection that I can make between PC and TV (and already have) is a gigabit ethernet connection.

Comment: @CharlesH RDP was the way to go. Downloaded a RDP app on my TV and now everything is working just fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do what you want with the model TV you want, so instead, I offer a work around solution:

Simply buy another PC or laptop, as cheap as you like, from a second hand site like Ebay, and use it to RDP through.

This way you can use the ethernet for the connection but have the box close enough to the TV to use the video cable of your choice.

Comment: I made one change into your story: I discovered last night that my TV is capable of doing RDP connections by himself. This is working. :-)